# Qt: The gdb process exited unexpectedly (code 127)

Tags: qt4, gdb, debian, qt-creator, qt4.7

What kinds of problem causes this Message Box with this message: **'The gdb process exited unexpectedly (code 127)'** after pressing  F5 or Start Debugging?
(I run QtCreator not as super user)

[image]

when I run QtCreator as Super User I got another message box with this message: **The gdb process failed to start. Either the invoked program 'gdb' is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program. No such file or directory**

[image]

When I run following message in terminal

```
gdb -ex
```

I get this error

> error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

but I have installed libncurses5 , libncursesw5, libncurses5-dev.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the debian's gdb pachage instead of QtSDK's gdb binary and the my problem was resolved

Answer (score 0):

This message usually raise up when you are checked "run in terminal" in run setting. Go to project tab and unchecked "run in terminal" in order to run program in application output in qt creator.

Or maybe you are calling gdb with bad parameter. Check this by call debugger in standalone without qtcreator.